# Count the integer solutions of $x_1+x_2-x_3+x_4-x_5=3$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

I am asking for help with solving this exercise:

Find the count of possible integer solutions for equation:

$$x_1+x_2-x_3+x_4-x_5=3$$

There are restrictions for possible values of $x$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&0 < x_1 \le 6\\
-&8 \le x_2 < -2\\
&x_3 \le 1\\
&3 < x_4\\
&2 \le x_5 \le 8
\end{aligned}
$$

Note: We should be able to find the count of solutions by using permutations and Inclusion-Exclusion principle.

Comment: what kind of numbers are you searching for? integers?

Comment: Yes, I am looking only for count of integer solutions

Comment: there are a lot of solutions

Comment: how can i send them to you?

Comment: i have wrote a lot of Solutions, but a finite set

Comment: I am looking only for count of the solutions, not for all exact solutions.

Comment: If you look for just integer solutions then I think that there may be infinite solutions because the constraints on $x_3$ and $x_4$ are not bounded from both sides. While if you ask for non negative integral solutions then the equation might have a finite number of solutions

Comment: I also think there should be a finite count of solutions. I am able to solve this type of exercise where there are only non-negative ${x}$ values with some nicer restrictions.

Comment: @Manthanein It has a finite number of solutions, since $x_3$ bounds $x_4$ and viceversa

Comment: Sorry I did not see the inequality correctly and misinterpreted it. Sorry for the mistake again

Comment: *For reference*, the answer I found using computer is $2016$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a simplification, transform$^\star$ $x_i$ to $y_i$ so that all variables are atleast positive.

$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3+y_4+y_5 = 15\\
y_1 \in [0,5]\\ 
y_2 \in [0,5] \\
y_3 \in [0,\infty] \\
y_4 \in [0, \infty] \\
 y_5 \in [0,6]  $$

Now the bounds in place, it is simple to use *inclusion exclusion principle*.

$$
\begin{align}
N &= N_{y_i \in [0, \infty)} \\ &- (N_{y_1 > 5} + N_{y_2 > 5} +N_{y_5 > 6})
\\ &+(N_{y_1 > 5 \land y_2 > 5} + N_{y_2 > 5  \land y_5 > 6}+N_{y_1 > 5 \land y_5 > 6}) \\
 &- (N_{y_1 > 5 \land y_2 > 5 \land y_5 > 6})
\end{align}
$$

Now the rest is pretty straight forward using the classic *stars and bars*:

$$\binom{19}{4} - \left(\binom{13}{4} +\binom{13}{4} +\binom{12}{4} \right)+\left(\binom{7}{4} +\binom{6}{4} +\binom{6}{4} \right)-0 = \boxed{\color{maroon} {2016}}$$

---

**Edit**

$^\star$In this edit I try to explain how we can *transform* the $x_i$ to $y_i$

1. We start with $x_1 \in [1,6]$, so $x_1 - 1 \in [0,5] $
2. Now $x_2 \in [-8,-2)$ or $x_2+8 \in [0,5]$
3. $x_3 \in (-\infty, 1]$ or $-x_3 \in [-1, \infty)$ and $-x_3+1 \in [0, \infty)$
4. And then $x_4 \in [4, \infty)$ so  $x_4-4 \in [0, \infty)$.
5. Lastly $x_5 \in [2,8]$ or $-x_5 \in [-8,-2]$ and $-x_5 + 8 \in [0,6]$

Now sum all the inequalities in the end of each numbered point. Call each expression in variable as new variable $y_i$. Required equation is:

$$(x_1 - 1) + (x_2+8) + (-x_3+1) + (x_4-4) + (-x_5+8 ) = 3 + (-1+8+1-4+8) \\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 = 15$$

Comment: @Abcd Thanks mate I was going to link this problem to you!

Comment: Can you tell me how you got $\dbinom{13}{4}$ for $y_1>5$?

Comment: @Abcd In that case we have $y_1 \in [6, \infty)$ so $y_1 - 6 \in [0,\infty)$, so that $(y_1 - 6) + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 = 15-6 = 9 $. Answer is from stars and bars, since all terms are non negative $\binom{9+5-1}{5-1}$

Comment: @samjoe Your math works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $-9\le a=x_1+x_2-x_5\le-5$; $b=-x_3+x_4\ge3$. Now you have 5 pairs of solutions $(-9,12),(-8,11),(-7,10),(-6,9),(-5,8)$. Let's start with $(-9,12)$.
$a=-9$ only when $x_1=1, \: x_2=-8, \: x_3=2$. Now $b=12$ when $x_3=-8, x_4=4$; $x_3=-7, x_4=5$; ..., $x_3=1, x_4=11$. That's 10 solutions.  Can you finish?

Comment: I think your boundaries are different then from @Manish Kundu

Comment: no, since $2+n\le 1$ and $4+n>3$, so $-1 <n\le -1$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the problem reduces to counting the solutions of $x_4-x_3=\alpha=3+a$, where $a=-x_1-x_2+x_5$. Now note that $a$ ranges between $-1$ and $15$, so that $\alpha$ takes on values between $2$ and $18$ respectively, which gives us $17$ different values for $\alpha$. With the constraints $x_4\ge4$ and $x_3\le1$ and the equation $x_4-x_3=\alpha$, it is possible to note that the number of solutions is finite.

Comment: False: $x_4 = 3+ x_5+x_3 -x_1-x_2 \le 3+8+1-0+8=20$

Comment: Oh, yes. One has to consider $x_3$ too.

Comment: There is no infinite solutions, $x_4$ is bounded below but $x_3$ is positive at some point.

Comment: Still false: $x+y=\alpha$ has finite solutions when, for example, $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$.

Comment: There are actually infinitely many solutions. See new edition.

Comment: @Allawonder False again: remember that $x_4 >3$ and $x_3\le 1$, so there's no solution of the kind $(4+n,2+n)$

Comment: I'm tired of baseless assertions. Did you actually check whether $(6,-3,2+n,4+n,2)$ satisfies the equation?

Comment: @Allawonder They satisfy the equation, but not the bounds! $2+n\le 1$ means $n\le -1$, and $4+n>3$ means $n>-1$, so there's no $n$ that satisfies the bounds

Comment: @Exodd This is true; I had completely ignored those restrictions. You have pointed out errors twice now. Thanks.

Comment: But then would that mean there are no solutions, for all the possible values of $\alpha$ fall in the range $[2,18]$?

Comment: @Allawonder, actually, you had the misfortune to pick the only value in that interval that is not admissible. If $\alpha=3$, then $x_4=4$, $x_3=1$ works (and it is the only couple that is a solution). If $\alpha = 10$, then $x_4=11-n$, $x_3 = 1 -n$ works for every $n\in[0,7]$, etc.

Comment: @Exodd Oh, I see. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 0):

I need help with solution too. On the picture is my try.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It is kinda the way how I wanted to be solved, but I think that answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

By translations $x\to x+c$ and symmetries $x\to-x$ you can reformulate your problem as

> Find all $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ integers that satisfy 
>   $$
> 1+x_3+x_4 = x_1+x_2+x_5$$
>   with bounds
>   $$0\le x_1\le 5\qquad 0\le x_2\le 5\qquad 0\le x_5\le 6$$
>   $$0\le x_3\qquad 0\le x_4$$

Now, call $p(n)$ the number of triples $(x_1,x_2,x_5)$ such that $x_1+x_2+x_5=n$ and such that
$$0\le x_1\le 5\qquad 0\le x_2\le 5\qquad 0\le x_5\le 6$$
hold. In the same way, let  $q(n)$ the number of couples $(x_3,x_4)$ such that $x_3+x_4=n$ and such that
$$0\le x_3\qquad 0\le x_4$$
hold. Your solution is
$$
p(1)q(0) + p(2)q(1) + p(3)q(2) + \dots + p(16)q(15).
$$
We know that $q(n)=n+1$, but $p(n)$ is much harder to compute, and I think must be done by a computer.

---

Let's do it with permutations/inclusion-exclusion.

First of all, a Toy Problem

> Find all $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ positive integers that satisfy 
>   $$c+x_3+x_4 = x_1+x_2+x_5$$
>   where $c$ is an integer (may be negative) and with bound
>   $$c + x_3+x_4\le n$$
>   where $n$ is a positive integer.

Like before, let $p(m)$ the number of triples $(x_1,x_2,x_5)$ such that $x_1+x_2+x_5=m$ and let  $q(m)$ the number of couples $(x_3,x_4)$ such that $x_3+x_4=m$. We know that
$$
p(m) = \frac{(m+2)(m+1)}2 = \binom{m+2}2 \qquad q(m) = m+1 = \binom{m+1}1
$$ 
The solution is 
$$TP(c,n) = q(-c)p(0) + q(1-c)p(1) + \dots +q(n-c)p(n) $$
$$ = \binom {1-c}1\binom 22 + \binom {2-c}1\binom 32 + \dots + \binom {n-c+1}1\binom {n+2}2 $$

---

If we return to our first problem, we can operate an inclusion-exclusion method.

- First of all, we notice that $x_1+x_2+x_5\le 16$, so we can consider the Toy Problem with $c=1$ and $n=16$, so we get $TP(1,16)$.
- We have to respect the bounds, though, so we have to subtract the wrong solutions. How many solution are there with $x_5>6$? If we substitute $x_5 = 7 +z_5$ we get again the Toy Problem with
  $$-6+x_3 + x_4 = x_1+x_2+z_5$$
  so $c=-6$ and $n=16 -7=9$, so $TP(-6,9)$. If we do the same for $x_1,x_2$ we get $TP(-5,10)$ twice.
- Now we subtracted too much. For example we subtracted twice the (wrong) solutions with $x_1>5,x_2>5$ and we have to add them again. With the same substitutions as before, we get $TP(-11,4)$. Doing the same for the other couples, we get  $TP(-12,3)$ twice.

The final answer is thus 
$$TP(1,16) - TP(-6,9) - 2\cdot TP(-5,10) + TP(-11,4) + 2\cdot TP(-12,3) $$

Comment: We should be able to find the count of solutions by using permutations and Inclusion–exclusion principle

Comment: Ok, now I'll write it. Warning: it'll be long